# WebStorm doesn't find errors in JavaScript code, the code is not highlighted in any way

Tags: javascript, node.js, compiler-errors, webstorm, syntax-highlighting

I tried invalidating and restarting the project, checked "File -> Settings > Editor -> File Types", go to "File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> JavaScript and Choose ECMAScript 5.1 and press OK. Then, open the menu again and re-select ECMAScript 6+, nothing worked.

[image]

Comment: 1) Show a screenshot of the whole IDE with such file opened-- it should show some details that you are omitting. Mainly want to see how it displays the file (at least few lines), file icon it uses. 2) Does it happen with other/similar files or just that one only? 3) Select this problematic file in the Project View panel, then invoke `View | Quick Definition` on it (`Ctrl+Q` here on Windows keymap). Then show a screenshot of the popup.

Comment: What about #2 and #3?

Comment: In either case: I do not like that yellowish background in the Project View panel. If it's a default color it suggests that those files are treated as Excluded / not part of the project. You may have some issue with the project config files (some files might be corrupted for some reason).

Comment: I suggest the following: 1) close the IDE 2) Go to the project root folder in Windows Explorer 3) backup and delete `.idea` subfolder (project settings are stored there) 4) Launch the IDE again and open the project (you can use `Open` action and point to the project root folder). The IDE will create a brand new project from those existing files. Lets see how it will behave now.

Comment: @LazyOne thank you, the last message helped me solve the problem